# Совмещение серверных и клиентских url в react-проекте

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Имеется проект на react и api на python/django, созданное под него. Api и приложение располагаются на одном домене, это части одного проекта. Для роутинга используется browserHistory.

Появилась проблема смешения урлов клиентской и серверной части. Допустим, когда я обращаюсь с страницы `mysite.com/elements/` к api по адресу `/api/v1/elements/carbon`

```js
axios.get(`api/v1/elements/${label}`).then(
        function(response) {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ELEMENT_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
                properties: response,
                isLoading: false
            });
        }
    )
```

я получаю 404 ошибку

```
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/elements/api/v1/elements/carbon 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Реакт-роутинг не делает разницы между серверным и клиентским урлом, что естественно.

Схема клиентского роутинга

```js
export const routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Properties} />
        <Route path='properties/:property' component={Properties} />
        <Route path='elements' component={Elements}>
            <Route path=':element' component={Elements} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='settings' component={Settings} />
        <Route path='download' component={Download} />
    </Route>
);
```

Подскажите, с какой стороны решать эту проблему и как совместить эти две схемы?

Решение с hashHistory знаю, но оно просто уродуем урлы и по сути не решение.

Comment: библиотека axios, с помощью которой Вы делаете запросы, никакого отношения к react-router не имеет. А подобное поведение скорее всего возникает из-за того, что Вы не указали baseURL.

Comment: @OlmerDale а разве речь была об axios? ну, могу использовать fetch.  я просто вставилкод для примера, а что проблема не в нем - знаю. что за baseURL и где указывают?

Comment: @OlmerDale добавил схему роутинга в вопрос

Comment: @OlmerDale какие альтернативы есть? чтобы меня урл при переходе по компонентам и обращаться к серверному api?

Comment: axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'; , но обычно пишут http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ - а тут уже подставляйте как хотите.

ещё желательно указать http|https

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.  В диспетчере урлов джанго, во всех запросах не связанных с апи, загрузкой статики и прочих заранее предусмотренных вещах, мы должны возвращать наше единственный шаблон `index.html` с скриптами, разместим в урлах следующую регулярку в самом конце

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

Все урлы будут обрабатывать согласно правилам выше, если урл не будет соответствовать ни одному шаблону, джанго возвратит `index.html` с скриптами, где роутингом уже занимется реакт.

Запрос к урлам api c генераторах экшнов остается без изменений

```js
import {
    GET_ELEMENT_DETAIL_REQUEST,
    GET_ELEMENT_DETAIL_SUCCESS
} from '../constants/Element'
import axios from 'axios'

export const getProperties = (label) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_ELEMENT_DETAIL_REQUEST,
        isLoading: true
    });

    axios.get(`/api/v1/elements/${label}/`).then(
        function(response) {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ELEMENT_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
                properties: response.data,
                isLoading: false
            });
        }
    )
};
```

Хотя правильнее будет сделать отдельный класс с методами запроса (head, get, post и прочие), которые будут возвращать промисы.